# Testing password against encrypted ext2 container

Tags: filesystems, encryption, cryptsetup, container

I have a encrypted container containing a mountable EXT2 file system with no partition table. How can I mount that file using cryptsetup? My attemps fail with 'VFS: cant find ext4 filesystem'...

Comment: Is the container encrypted using `plain` mode or `luks` mode?

Comment: It should be plain mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To open and mount an encrypted container using plain mode:

```
sudo cryptsetup plainOpen Container DecryptedContainter
sudo mount /dev/mapper/DecryptedContainer /mnt
```

When you are done, unmount and close the container:

```
sudo umount /mnt
sudo cryptsetup plainClose DecryptedContainer
```

Use the appropriate names for `Container` and `DecryptedContainer`, and the correct mount point instead of `/mnt`.

From `man cryptsetup`:

```
The following are valid plain device type actions:

   open --type plain <device> <name>
   create <name> <device> (OBSOLETE syntax)

          Opens (creates a mapping with) <name> backed by device <device>.

          <options> can be [--hash, --cipher, --verify-passphrase,  --key-
          file,  --keyfile-offset,  --key-size,  --offset, --skip, --size,
          --readonly, --shared, --allow-discards]

          Example: 'cryptsetup open --type plain /dev/sda10 e1'  maps  the
          raw encrypted device /dev/sda10 to the mapped (decrypted) device
          /dev/mapper/e1, which can then be mounted,  fsck-ed  or  have  a
          filesystem created on it.
```

Comment: Thank your for the answer! I will try it tomorrow. To define cipher mode and key length I have to use parameters with the cryptsetup command? I want to supply the password via the key file parameter too.